# Understanding hibernate relationships

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have an Entity Student and I have another entity called Scores

Every Student has a Scores which has three types of scores

So there is a `OnetoOne` relationship between these objects? Or should it be a `OneToMany` relationship between a Student and Scores?

To be clear , here is teh scores object

```
Scores

Int MathScore;
Int SciScore;
```

I cant save this to the database. The score_id field n the student table is always null

Comment: It depends on the design you choose. But "a student has a scores" already looks wrong. Either he has a score (without s), or he has many scores (with an s).

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you want to do with it but if 1 student has 1 score and 1 score only has 1 student. Then yes, OnetoOne is a good choise.

> Every Student has a Scores which has three types of scores

I would do this with an enum.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Not sure why I see the ID as null for the scores in the student table

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example.

OneToOne

```
@Entity    
class Student {

@OneToOne
private Scores scores;

}
```

OneToMany

```
@Entity    
class Student {

@OneToMany
private List<Scores> scoresList;

}
```

will be better to use Score entity or in case of plural List